# Symfony Service Parameters

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, containers

How do you specify the parameters of a service. Following the Symfony documentation I created my own service by adding it to the config.yml file within my bundle.

```
    system_info_memory:
        class:        "%system_info.memory.class%"
        arguments:    ['enviroment']
```

This works perfectly in my controller by calling:

```
$service = $this->get('system_info_memory');
```

However I have seen nothing about how to actually set the argument to my service dynamically, the above just statically passes the string 'environment' into the classes constructor. However I would it to pass in the value of:

```
$this->container->get( 'kernel' )->getEnvironment()
```

Before getting an instance of the class from the container.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the `kernel.environment` parameter:

```
services:
    system_info_memory:
        class:     %system_info.memory.class%
        arguments: [ %kernel.environment% ]
```

Comment: What happens if I wanted to pass something other than a service?

Comment: @Ben_hawk you can pass service, parameter and plain value: `arguments: [@service_id, "plain_value", %parameter%]`

Answer (score 2):

There are mainly two types of Dependency Injection. In Symfony we also have an extra way. I explain all of them here:

**1- Constructor injection**

This method requires the client to provide parameters in the constructor of a service, which Symfony will do for you if you define the service parameters in the config file.

```
saman.search:
    class: Saman\SearchBundle\Services\SearchService
    arguments: 
      - @translator
      - @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
      - %search_service_parameters%
```

And in your service class you have:

```
<?php

namespace Library\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator;

class SearchService
{
    /**
     * Translator services
     * 
     * @var TranslatorService $translatorService
     */
    protected $translatorService;
    
    /**
     *
     * @var EntityManager $em
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * Client side parameters
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected $parameters;

    public function __construct(
        TranslatorService $translatorService, 
        EntityManager $em,
        array $parameters = array()
        )
    {
        $this->translatorService = $translatorService;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        return $this->translatorService->trans('app.text.hello');  
    }
}
?>
```

**2- Setter injection**

This method requires your service to provide a setter method for each dependency.
When you want to use that service you set the dependency dynamically.
This gives you the freedom of setting dependencies at any time.

```
saman.search:
    class: Saman\SearchBundle\Services\SearchService
    arguments: 
      - @translator
      - @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
      - %search_service_parameters%

saman.a:
    class: Saman\SearchBundle\Services\A
    arguments: ~
```

And in your service you have:

```
<?php

namespace Library\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator;
use Library\Services\A;

class SearchService
{
    /**
     * Translator services
     * 
     * @var TranslatorService $translatorService
     */
    protected $translatorService;
    
    /**
     *
     * @var EntityManager $em
     */
    protected $em;
    
    /**
     * Service A
     * @var A $a
     */
    protected $a;
  
    /**
     * Client side parameters
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected $parameters;

    public function __construct(
        TranslatorService $translatorService, 
        EntityManager $em,
        array $parameters = array()
        )
    {
        $this->translatorService = $translatorService;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }

    public function setServiceA(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;

        return $this;
    }

    public function doSomethingNeedServiceA()
    {
        return $this->getServiceA()->doSomethingInA();  
    }

    private function getServiceA()
    {
        if (null === $this->a) {
            throw new \LogicException("You should set service A first");  
        }

        return $this->a;
    }
}
?>
```

This can also be improved by using interfaces

```
<?php

namespace Library\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator;
use Library\Interfaces\A;

class SearchService
{
    /**
     * Translator services
     * 
     * @var TranslatorService $translatorService
     */
    protected $translatorService;
    
    /**
     *
     * @var EntityManager $em
     */
    protected $em;
    
    /**
     * Interfaces A
     * @var A $a
     */
    protected $a;
  
    /**
     * Client side parameters
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected $parameters;

    public function __construct(
        TranslatorService $translatorService, 
        EntityManager $em,
        array $parameters = array()
        )
    {
        $this->translatorService = $translatorService;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }

    public function setServiceA(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        
        return $this; 
    }

    public function doSomethingNeedServiceA()
    {
        return $this->getServiceA()->doSomethingInA();  
    }

    private function getServiceA()
    {
        if (null === $this->a) {
            throw new \LogicException("You should set a service that implement A interfaces");  
        }

        return $this->a;
    }
}
?>
```

And your interface

```
<?php

namespace Library\Interfaces;

interface A
{
    public function doSomethingInA();
}
?>
```

Then when you want to use this service you should do

```
$aService = $this->get('saman.a');
$searchService = $this->get('saman.search');

$searchService->setServiceA($aService)
    ->doSomethingNeedServiceA();
```

**3- Tagged Services**

In Symfony there is a method for registering a Service in another Service, using the tags configuration. See [Working with Tagged Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html)

I have implemented this method in the past and it is so good, but it is big. If somebody needs the implementation I would be happy to put it here.